# Jquery Expanding Div MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Total noob at jquery and thought id try a simple expanding div. This seems to do nothing. Can anyone explain where i have gone wrong please?

Thanks

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='qD.qY']").click(function () {
            var test = $(this).val();

            $("div.desc").hide();
            $("#Q" + test).show();
        });
    });

</script>



 <div class="editor-field">           
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.qD.qY, "0") No
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.qD.qY, "1") Yes
 </div>

 <div id="Q0" class="desc">
     No
 </div>
 <div id="Q1" class="desc" style="display: none;">
    Yes
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `$` doesn't mean jquery on your page, Try this way:

```
  jQuery(function($){
    $("input[name$='qD.qY']").click(function () {
         $("div.desc").not(jQuery("#Q" + this.value).show()).hide();
         //or $("#Q" + this.value).show().siblings('div.desc').hide();
     });
   });
```

Also note that this will generate the elements with duplicate ids, no visible harm but it will make your html invalid. So try to override the id as well.

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.qD.qY, "0", new {@id= "qD_qY_0"}) No
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.qD.qY, "1", new {@id= "qD_qY_1"}) Yes
```

Comment: damn, you were miliseconds faster than me :)

Comment: Thanks for your time. My radiobuttons are being rendered as follows with your adjustments and still having no luck <input checked="checked" id="qD_qY_1" name="qD.qY" type="radio" value="1">

Comment: @loveforfire33 Try `$("input[id^='qD_qY']").click..` Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @PSL No i dont see any errors, your code works perfectly in jsfiddle. So i think it may be something else.

Comment: @loveforfire33 ok do one thing... do a `console.log($("input[name$='qD_qY']").length)` before the click event as see what is returned. Probably `$` doesn't mean jquery in your page, so also try replacing `$` with `jQuery`  and verify.

Comment: ok so i tried both console.log(jQuery( and console.log($( both have an uncaught reference error: is not defined. (sorry if this is not what i am meant to do - im very new to jquery! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @loveforfire33 Do you have jquery included in your page? Where have you included jquery? is it after this script?

Comment: i think so <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> - yes it is after.

Comment: @loveforfire33 Possibly jquery is included after this script or you have a 404. Check your network console to see if jquery is loaded and also what are all the errors logged in the console?

Comment: ahh it was a 404. Thanks!